# postgres diff tool

Tags: postgresql, diff

Can anyone recommend a good UI driven diff tool (schema and data) for comparing Postgres databases?  Preferable something that runs on Windows as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the relevant [section](http://www.postgresql.org/download/products/1) of the Postgres' "Software Catalogue" and also search the [projects](http://pgfoundry.org/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=diff&Search=Search) in pgFoundry.